# Select Multiple Rows Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, selection, rows

I am trying to select multiple rows (limited) in the table. I can select and receive data from that selection now but I would like to limit my selection. I would like to create a table that user can select only 6(limited) rows. After 6 rows are selected, I want to stop click event.

I tried like this but it doesnt work because event can not be stopped.

```
var selectedRows = 0;

if(selectedRows < 6) {
    $("#table1 tr").click( function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")) console.log("already chosen");
        else {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var id = $("th",this).html();
            selectedRows++;
            console.log(selectedRows, teamNo);
        }
    });
} else {
    console.log("you've chosen 6 rows !");
}
```

edit: Also I want to add this feature.

If the user selects 6 rows and s/he continues to select more, the first selection changes with 7th selection and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the condition inside the function:

```
var selectedRows = 0;

$("#table1 tr").click( function(event){
  if($(this).hasClass("selected")) console.log("already chosen");
  else {
    if(selectedRows <= 6) {
      $(this).addClass("selected");
      var id = $("th",this).html();
      selectedRows++;
      console.log(selectedRows, teamNo);
    }
    else {
      console.log("you've chosen 6 rows !");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks you are so right, that works. I dont know how i failed to notice this :) I tried to write before click event and it is exactly same with the version in the question.

Comment: Given this, you could create a method like 'selectOption(elem)', so you don't confuse what happens inside the click event and what happens outside.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the user has selected more than 6 WITHIN the click function, and then fire the actions IF the user has not selected 6. You just have it flipped.

```
    $("#table1 tr").click( function(){
        if(selectedRows <= 6) {
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")) console.log("already chosen");
            else {
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                var id = $("th",this).html();
                selectedRows++;
                console.log(selectedRows, teamNo);
            }
        } else {
            console.log("you've chosen 6 rows !");
        }
    });
```